# MFMailComposeViewController is not working under iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

`[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]` works well under iOS 6 application, but fail for under iOS7.

iOS 6 mail function:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailer setSubject:@"A Message from Bloomingkids"];
    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"support@bloomingkids.com", nil];
    [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bloomingKidsLogo.png"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
    [mailer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"Images"];
    NSString *emailBody = @"Have you seen the Bloomingkids web site?";
    [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
    [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failure"
                                                    message:@"Your device doesn't support the composer sheet"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Note: It's working on simulator but not on iPad. The error was **Your device doesn't support composer sheet**

Comment: Do you have an email account setup on the device?

Comment: no, i didn't… it is necessary

Comment: How do you expect to send email with no account setup?

Comment: Yes it is mandotary to your device must configure with mail Account.

Comment: Then how did it worked on `iOS 6` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add any email account in your device means setup an email account...